# Complicated Website Structure - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I what I consider to be an advanced beginner with Ruby on Rails (and web design in general). I have this project and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to implement a recent development.

Initially the project was a simple blog for businesses to post articles that promote their company. It was meant for businesses in a specific town only and I had no trouble setting that up. Now we're trying to broaden out and let the site cater to many towns.

We want to have a home page where you select a town. That takes you to a list of blog posts from businesses in that town. You can navigate to a directory, contact us form, profile page etc. My problem is, I'd like each town to act like mini-site, so the directory only shows business associated with the town and the header image changes to reflect which town you've chosen.

My initial approach to this problem was to set up a towns scaffold and put in associations between towns, users and posts. The problem is 'storing' the chosen town somehow so that I can, for example, show only businesses for a specific town in the directory.

At the moment I have, in the posts model

```
belongs_to :user
```

In the user model

```
has_many :posts
has_many :towns
```

I have an action in towns controller to handle the directory which only has the line:

```
@users = User.order('trading_name ASC').where(:town => @town.id.to_s)
```

and then I want to display those users in the directory view.

I also have the following in my towns controller

```
before_action :set_town, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :directory]
```

To be honest though, I can't fully wrap my head around the associations needed or even if this is the correct path to take. As it stands I get the following error when I try to access the directory view

```
Couldn't find Town without an ID
```

and it references the following method in towns controller (I'm using the friendly_id gem)

```
def set_town
  @town = Town.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

Am I heading down the correct route with these associations (and missing something) or is there a better approach I could be taking. Also, I hope I've explained myself clearly. Please ask if there's something that's confusing.

Comment: You can either store it in session or a cookie then have a `before_action` on your application controller to find it if the cookie/session is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your requirements are, but I'd say:

A user probably doesn't "have many" towns.

A user does "have many" posts.
A town does "have many" posts.

A post belongs to a town, and also a user.

Then, on your home page, you'd have a form with a drop-downlist of towns, and it should sumbit to an action like `choose_town` or something.

Your `choose_town` action should save the name or id of the town in a Cookie. You know about cookies? They basically allow you to save little bits of info between requests, for a specific user. They are stored in a users browser, but are sent back/forth from the server on every request. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#cookies

Then, your `set_town` method, called every request, will look in the cookie to find the right town.

edit: @japed mentioned session, along with cookies. The session is identified by a cookie - however, information stored in the session is saved on the server, and is not sent back and forth between the browser and the server. In this case, either one is probably fine.

Comment: Well my users are the businesses themselves and some are franchises so they'll belong to more than one town. Your explanation make a lot of sense to me. I'll try and put in these changes and let you know if they work.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. This approach has worked pretty much perfectly for me. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with your project.